# Stutter in collision code. While the code works, the player object stops for just a sec right before it collides. Monogame

Tags: c#, game-engine, game-physics, collision, monogame

This is my collision code. The problem is with the code that eases the object into the wall instead of stopping it right before the wall.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUVPl.jpg Video of the Issue.

```
 private void CheckCollisionsAndMove(Map map)
        {
            collided = Rectangle.Empty;
            ///Walls
            tPos = position;
            //Check X
            position.X += move.X;
            for (int i = 0; i<map.walls.Count; i++)
            {
                 collided = map.CheckCollision(BoundingBox);
            }
            position = tPos;

            if (collided != Rectangle.Empty)
            {
                while (collided == Rectangle.Empty)
                {
                    position.X += (move.X / System.Math.Abs(move.X));
                    for (int i = 0; i < map.walls.Count; i++)
                    {
                        collided = map.CheckCollision(BoundingBox);
                    }
                }
                //position.X -= (move.X / System.Math.Abs(move.X));
                move.X = 0;
                decide.X = 0;
            }
            //Position
            position.X += move.X;

            //Check Y
            collided = Rectangle.Empty;
            position.Y += move.Y;
            for (int i = 0; i < map.walls.Count; i++)
            {
                collided = map.CheckCollision(BoundingBox);
            }
            position.Y = tPos.Y;

            if (collided != Rectangle.Empty)
            {
                while (collided == Rectangle.Empty)
                {
                    position.Y += (move.Y / System.Math.Abs(move.Y));
                    for (int i = 0; i < map.walls.Count; i++)
                    {
                        collided = map.CheckCollision(BoundingBox);
                    }
                }
                //position.Y -= (move.Y / System.Math.Abs(move.Y));
                move.Y = 0;
                decide.Y = 0;
            }
            //Position
            position.Y += move.Y;
        }
```

Thanks in advance imma go stare at this for an hour.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what is exactly happening since I do not see how you actually deal with for example velocities, but what I can see is that something is wrong inside of your if statements. The statements in the `while (collided == Rectangle.Empty)` will never be called since the if condition only evaluates to true when `collided != Rectangle.Empty`. This means that inside of the if, collided will never be Rectangle.Empty, so the whole while loop is never utilized and position.y is not changed. This also means that if at one point a collision is detected, your entity will always have a move.Y of 0 and will simply not move. Considering the fact that your entity does still move, I would assume that the velocity is reset elsewhere and the collision is not detected next iteration (maybe because of a decrease in velocity, hence different collisiondistance?).